# LogCat is not showing null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, logcat

My LogCat is often not showing null pointer exceptions..

Sample:

```
ProgressDialog pd;
ps.show();
```

Application stops (do not reacts for any action), but there is no information about any reason in logcat.
Another sample is with database - if there is no DB and I'm making actions on it, the same happens.
I tried (that action with DB) on my colleague's phone and there was normal error. I have all needed programmer options in my phone turned on.
Maybe someone know , why it is so? It was not burdensome, when I had small app, but now when it's bigger, it can be really frustrating.

Comment: Remove any filter in the adb panel from DDMS

Comment: Please provide more information, which IDE, do you get any information at all? Does logs show?

Comment: SimonMarquis: I'm looking into panel without filter - no changes.
Rawa: I'm using AndroidStudio with logcat in AndroidDeviceMonitor. I'm getting other logs in normal way.

Comment: Is there any log displayed associated to your app or nothing is shown?

Comment: The code you posted references two different variables, so it's probably not what you are testing.  Does the code you are testing have any catch blocks or other exception handlers which might consume the NPE before it falls through to the system and gets logged by that?  If so, you should call the printStackTrace() method on the exception delivered to each of them.

Comment: More important question - **without the log, how do you even know that you have an NPE?**  If it's because you are running in the debugger, you may have to let it run a bit further to get into the Exception handler which normally logs this fact.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If I've understood you properly (because I'm not sure :D), the answer is, that I'm not using any breakpoints, so it is not a problem with letting application to run further.

Comment: Again, **how do you even know there is an NPE?**

Comment: calling methods on object which is null should throw NPE?

Answer (score 0):

I get this with android studio too...

Close android studio, restart ADB, and generally it starts working for me.

If that does not work then put a breakpoint at the line `.show();` ... Then open up the logcat and then skip over the breakpoint. It then shows, I have similar issues.

> (Windows 7 64 bit - Android Studio 0.82)

Answer (score 0):

I dont like the IDE logcat option honestly.

The SDK comes with an adb binary, use the logcat option from there via

`adb logcat` or my personal favorite built in alias, `adb lolcat`

This will give you the log information for EVERYTHING happening on the device, and can be useful tracking down issues caused by device state.

For example, you can see network changes in the logcat, and if your app crashes on network call you wouldnt have any idea why if you just used the logcat output from your app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using: `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` in my application file. If that is not turned off during debugging you won't see any exception output. ( Just make sure to turn it back on again when you release so you can still handle your issues ).